# How to check lowerCamelCase string with condition with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regex for the endpoint which can validate a string for lowercase (or concatenated with `-` )

BUT if there is a curly braces, then a word inside a curly braces should be in lowerCamelCase.

Here is an example string:

```
/v1/accounts/{accountNumber}/balances
OR /v1/user-account/balances-sheet
```

I am using a following regex `'^[\/a-z\{\}]+$'` to validate above examples but not getting the point how I can validate curly braces condition OR if it possible to combine in single Regex?

Comment: `accountNumber` is not in UpperCamelCase; it's just camelCase. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to validate both cases:

```bash
^(?:\/\{[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*)*\}|\/\w+(?:-\w+)*)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JxCgzN/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\/\{[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*)*\}`: Match `/` followed by variable name that would be `{<lowerCamelCase>}`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\/\w+(?:-\w+)*`: Match `/` followed by valid path component that may have 0 or more hyphen separated words
- `)+`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `$`: End

Comment: This seems to be not validating lowerCamelCase within {}

Comment: That's not correct. You can see `/v1/accounts/{accountNumber}/balances` being validated in the linked demo.

Answer (score 1):

The regex to match both of your examples would be `^([a-z0-9\/\-]+)(\{(?<Token>[\w\/]+)\})?([a-z0-9\/\-]+)?$` -- check it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2c4A48/1)

[image: Regex 101]

Comment: This will also match `/v1/accounts/{ABC}/balances` or `/v1/accounts/{____}/balances`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(\/([\da-z]+(-[\da-z]+)?|\{[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*}))+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/0wPlB6zw2MmUy1).